# How to remove black background from this JS coding?

Tags: javascript, css, background, transparency, particles

I'm trying to make this particle text be on a transparent background to add onto a slideshow. Can someone assist? I cannot seem to find where it is stated within the code.

Here is the JS code. Sorry I can't seem to get it to fit properly within the code section of the post.

> class Particles {   constructor(x, y, texture, size) {
> this.x = x;
> this.y = y;
>
> ```
> this.sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(new PIXI.Texture.from(texture));
>
> this.sprite.texture.frame = new PIXI.Rectangle(x, y, size, size);
>
> this.sprite.x = x;
> this.sprite.y = y;
>
> this.speedX = 0;
> this.speedY = 0;
>
> this.radius = 100;
>
> this.gravity = 0.1;
>
> this.maxGravity = 0.01 + Math.random() * 0.03;
>
> this.friction = 0.9;
>
> this.dirX = Math.random() - 0.5;
> this.dirY = Math.random() - 0.5;   }
> ```
>
> update(mouse) {
> const distanceX = mouse.x - this.sprite.x;
> const distanceY = mouse.y - this.sprite.y;
>
> ```
> const distanceSqrd = distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY;
>
> if (distanceSqrd < this.radius * this.radius && distanceSqrd > 0) {
>   const distance = Math.sqrt(distanceSqrd);
>
>   let normalX = distanceX / distance;
>   let normalY = distanceY / distance;
>
>   this.speedX -= normalX;
>   this.speedY -= normalY;
>
>   this.gravity *= this.friction;
> } else {
>   this.gravity += 0.1 * (this.maxGravity - this.gravity);
> }
>
> let oDistX = this.x - this.sprite.x;
> let oDistY = this.y - this.sprite.y;
>
> this.speedX += oDistX * this.gravity;
> this.speedY += oDistY * this.gravity;
>
> this.speedX *= this.friction;
> this.speedY *= this.friction;
>
> this.sprite.x += this.speedX;
> this.sprite.y += this.speedY;   } }
> ```
>
> class ParticlesText {   constructor({ text, size }) {
> this.app = new PIXI.Application({ width: innerWidth, height: innerHeight });
>
> ```
> document.querySelector("#content-canvas").append(this.app.view);
>
> this.text = text;
> this.size = size;
>
> this.cols = 500;
> this.rows = 200;
>
> this.pSize = 2;
> this.particles = [];
>
> this.mouse = {x: 0, y: 0}
>
> this.container = new PIXI.particles.ParticleContainer(50000);
> this.app.stage.addChild(this.container);
>
> this.onResize = this.onResize.bind(this);   }
> ```
>
> init() {
> const that = this;
> opentype.load(
> "https://raw.githack.com/AlainBarrios/Fonts/master/LeagueSpartan-Bold.otf",
> function(err, font) {
> if (err) {
> alert("Font could not be loaded: " + err);
> } else {
> const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
>
> ```
>       // Now let's display it on a canvas with id "canvas"
>       const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
>
>       // Construct a Path object containing the letter shapes of the given text.
>       // The other parameters are x, y and fontSize.
>       // Note that y is the position of the baseline.
>       const path = font.getPath(that.text, 0, that.size, that.size);
>       const width = font.getAdvanceWidth(that.text, that.size);
>
>       that.cols = width;
>       that.rows = that.size;
>
>       canvas.width = width;
>       canvas.height = that.size;
>
>       path.fill = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
>       // If you just want to draw the text you can also use font.draw(ctx, text, x, y, fontSize).
>       path.draw(ctx);
>
>       that.addObjects(canvas, ctx);
>     }
>   }
> );   }
> ```
>
> isEmpty(x, y, ctx) {
> const image = ctx.getImageData(x, y, this.pSize, this.pSize);
>
> ```
> let emptyCounter = 0;
>
> for (let i = 0; (length = image.data.length), i < length; i += 4) {
>   if (image.data[i + 3] !== 0) {
>     continue;
>   }
>   emptyCounter++;
> }
>
> return emptyCounter === this.pSize * this.pSize;   }
> ```
>
> addObjects(canvas, ctx) {
> this.container.x = this.app.renderer.width / 2 - this.cols / 2;
> this.container.y = this.app.renderer.height / 2 - this.rows / 2;
>
> ```
> for (let i = 0; i < this.cols; i += 1) {
>   for (let j = 0; j < this.rows; j += 1) {
>     const x = i * this.pSize;
>     const y = j * this.pSize;
>
>     if (this.isEmpty(x, y, ctx)) continue;
>
>     const p = new Particles(x, y, canvas, this.pSize);
>
>     this.particles.push(p);
>     this.container.addChild(p.sprite);
>   }
> }
>
> this.container.interactive = true;
>
> this.onResize();
> window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
>
> this.container.on("mousemove", e => {
>   this.mouse = e.data.getLocalPosition(this.container);
> });
>
> this.animate();   }
> ```
>
> onResize() {
> const { innerWidth, innerHeight } = window;
> const size = [innerWidth, innerHeight];
> const ratio = size[0] / size[1];
>
> ```
> if (innerWidth / innerHeight >= ratio) {
>   var w = innerHeight * ratio;
>   var h = innerHeight;
> } else {
>   var w = innerWidth;
>   var h = innerWidth / ratio;
> }
>
> //this.app.renderer.view.style.width = w + "px";
> //this.app.renderer.view.style.height = h + "px";   }
> ```
>
> animate() {
> this.app.ticker.add(() => {
> stats.begin();
>
> ```
>   this.particles.forEach(p => {
>     p.update(this.mouse);
>   });
>
>   stats.end();
> });   } }
> ```
>
> const particles = new ParticlesText({ text: "KILL THE ROBOTS", size:
> 150 }); particles.init();

Comment: Again, defaulted, the text at the bottom that says "KILL THE ROBOTS" is white on a black background. I would initially like the bg to be transparent. But I cannot find the properties that state the bg needs to be black.

Comment: Right click on your browser with the code running and select `inspect`, then inspect the element and its css.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything. I still cannot find the code imitating the back background,